# redirect after video is finished

Tags: redirect, mediaelement.js

I'm new to mediaelements.js

at the end of my video, I wish that the user is redirected to another page

I have tried something like

```
<script>
$(function(){
        $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
            success: function(player, node) {
                window.location = "http://google.com";
                });
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

but I have not been successfull at all, maybe someone would have an idea

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. 'player1' is the id of the video

```
<script>
new MediaElement('player1', {

success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 

// add event listener
mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {

       //Do Stuff here
       //alert("sometext"); 
       window.location = "http://google.com";

        }, false);
    },
});
</script>
```

The code I posted was for the media element player. I looks like you're using the video.js player in the link you posted. I'm not sure how that would work but I did find this... [help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/26-redirect-to-url-once-video-has-ended](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/26-redirect-to-url-once-video-has-ended)

Comment: thank you ShockTower, would you have a url with a functionable version cause I just can't get it work my current url is http://www.atanahoue.com/video/video-js/ thank you in advance

Comment: oups, I have tried with the wrong js library, please forgive me

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you very much, and please forgive my stupindess